# Drupal 7 globalredirect not working for /node/ redirection

Tags: 7, nodes, redirection

I want to redirect my site from URLs like

`/node/530`

to

`/Services/TrainTickets.html`

I installed GlobalRedirect module as I've read it would address this problem, but the same page is still accessible at `/node/530` path.

Anybody knows what the problem could be and how I could resolve it?

I also want to make it impossible to access the site via

`http://www.waytorussia.net/node?page=31` and so on...

Thanks!

UPDATE I use Drupal for Facebook module and I've seen there were issues with that as it uses custom url rewrite but did not find any resolution.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem why are you not simply using Clean URLs, which is built into Drupal? I'm assuming you're using version 7.x.

I'm not absolutely certain about adding the *.html* added to your url aliases and whether that will break something, but I'd imagine you could easily fix that by using some mod_rewrite and just appending *.html* to all your clean URLs.

What I mean then is in your Drupal system your URL aliases will be */Services/TrainTickets*. Essentially you'll still be using default/core clean URLs for all your paths. In **.htaccess** file though you can use *mod_rewrite* to append *.html* to all your paths.

For your last problem re: blocking access to all */node/x* paths, the first thing I thought of was again to use *mod_rewrite* to redirect to a custom built 404 Page Not Found page, instead of having to use a Drupal module. However, I've never tried this and am not certain this approach would work. I took a quick look though and it appears someone else thought of this too:

https://www.drupal.org/node/164526#comment-7919767

One issue I see right away is that you'd want to ensure that the path is a node view page (i.e. node/x) and nothing more (e.g node/x/edit - which would mean you're logged in), otherwise you'll run into some issues when logged in and trying to edit content.

Maybe try it out? Worth a shot.

Comment: I'm using cleanurls of course, but that doesn't solve the issue, because that module doesn't redirect /node/xx to a canonical url.